# IOS/Objective-C: Determine when asynchronous download has finished before saving data

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a tableview in which the photos are downloaded from the web.  The remote photos are downloaded asynchronously using a category for this purpose.  During the download, a local image is displayed until the download is complete when the image from the web replaces the placeholder  All this works fine.  My problem is I need to identify when the new image has been loaded in order to save it locally.

Here is the code in custom tableview cell that displays and tries to save the image.  The problem is that it sometimes saves the placeholder and other times saves the web image depending on how fast the download occurs.

```
NSString *picURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.~.com/pics/%@",item.pic];
NSString *picname = item.pic;
[self.iconView setImageWithRemoteFileURL:picURL placeHolderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item.jpg"]]; //this method is in a category
//Only want to do following after the asynchronous download is finished...
[self saveImage:self.iconView asPic:picname];
```

Here is some of the code in the category however, I've been unable to get the delegate pattern to work.  Wondering if there is an alternative way.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //done downloading data - process completed!
    [self.delegate didCompleteDownloadForURL:self.url withData:self.data];

}

#pragma mark DownloadHelperDelegate

-(void)didCompleteDownloadForURL:(NSString *)url withData:(NSMutableData *)data
{
    //handles the downloaded image data, turns it into an image instance and saves then it into the ImageCache singleton.

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    if (image == nil) {//something didn't work out - data may be corrupted or a bad url
        return;
    }

    //cache the image
    ImageCache *imageCache = [UIImageView imageCache];
    [imageCache storeCachedImage:image forURL:url];

    //update the placeholder image display of this UIImageView
    self.image = image;


 //At this point I have the image but how do I start save.  
I could put the save code right here but this is a category that
 gets reused in multiple places and the save code would vary 
depending on where it is used.
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Where do you set the delegate?

Comment: what do you mean by "set" the delegate?  A protocol is specified in the category but it is a funky category (I got elsewhere) that has hidden methods in it.  The category is included in the tableview cell.  I tried having the cell subscribe to the protocol but get warning that protocol is not defined.  In any case protocol method does not fire in cell.  I asked a separate question on getting delegate to work but got no answers.  This question is searching for alternatives to the delegate approach.

Comment: Something somewhere needs to set the delegate such that `self.delegate` returns something other than `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use NSURLSession or something similar in your download helper category:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.lombax.it/ok.gif"]] completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    // here, the file download has finished and you can copy it and assign to the icon file
    NSLog(@"File location is: %@", location);
}];
[task resume];
```